# SVG: Changing Line Color Mid-Path

Tags: svg

So, I want to create multiple polylines using a path. Some of these polylines, I want in a different color. Is there a way to change the color mid-path?

I'm guessing the answer is no. I would need to draw different colored lines using a different path. Just checking to see if I've missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, but I don't think it is possible to change the color of a stroke/path midway.
It's not an option in Photoshop, Illustrator, InkScape, or any vector graphic software I know; so I really doubt it is possible with current technology...

Comment: OK, perhaps I didn't make myself clear. Let's say my path drew 10 polylines. I want one of those to appear in green, and all the others in black. That's what I meant. It sounds like you might have thought I wanted part of one line to appear in green.

Comment: Even if the different parts of a path are disconnected, it is still treated as a single element as far as styling is concerned.  If you want part of the drawing to be styled differently, you need to make it a separate element.  (Except for certain limited cases where you can create a gradient that exactly matches the color changes you want, as Erik Dahlstrom suggested).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the path, but you can do this with a gradient stroke in some cases.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" x1="298" y1="0" x2="304" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
            <stop stop-color="red" offset="0.01"/>
            <stop stop-color="red" offset="0.7"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="0.7"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polyline points="20 20 300 20 300 100 400 100" stroke="url(#grad)" fill="none" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/706go2ct/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Erik. I'm not sure this will work for my application, but I will play around with it some. I think ultimately I'll have to create a separate path for the highlighted line. But your brief snippet shows me stuff I've yet to encounter in my SVG studies. So thanks for that as well.